# openpyxl Python Iterating Through Large Data List

Tags: python, excel, duplicates, openpyxl

I have a large excel workbook with 1 sheet with roughly 45,000 rows and 45 columns. I want to iterate through the columns looking for duplicates and unique items and its taking a very long time to go through individual columns. Is there anyway to optimize my code or make this go faster? I either want to print the information or save to txt file. I'm on windows 10 and python 2.7 using openpyxl module:

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook, worksheet, Workbook
    import os

    #read work book to get data
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'file') 
    wb = load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx', read_only=True)

    count = 0
    seen = set()
    uniq = []

    for cell in ws.columns[0]:
       if cell not in seen:
         uniq.append(cell)
         seen.add(cell)

    print("Unique: "+uniq)
    print("Doubles: "+seen)
```

EDIT: Lets say I have 5 columns A,B,C,D,E and 10 entries, so 10 rows, 5x10. In column A I want to extract all the duplicates and separate them from the unique values.

Comment: You should use Pandas. It already has methods to filter out duplicate and unique rows.

Comment: are you looking for duplicates in each column? could you provide a sample data set (5-7 rows) and desired output based on the sample data set?

Comment: I will check out the pandas module and yes I am looking for duplicate and unique entries for each in cell in 1 column for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VedangMehta mentioned, Pandas will do it very quickly for you.

#### Run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
#read in the dataset:
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = 'file')

df_dup = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())

#save duplicated values from first column
df[df_dup].iloc[:,0].to_csv("file_duplicates_col1.csv")

#save unique values from first column
df[~df_dup].iloc[:,0].to_csv("file_unique_col1.csv")

#save duplicated values from all columns:
df[df_dup].to_csv("file_duplicates.csv")

#save unique values from all columns:
df[df_dup].to_csv("file_unique.csv")
```

#### For details, see below:

Suppose your dataset looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,1,13], 'b':[13,3,5,3]})
df.head()
Out[24]:
    a   b
0   1  13
1   3   3
2   1   5
3  13   3
```

You can find which values are duplicated in each column:

```
df_dup = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())
```

the result:

```
df_dup

Out[26]:
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3  False   True
```

you can find the duplicated values by subsetting the `df` using the boolean dataframe `df_dup`

```
df[df_dup]
Out[27]:
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0
```

Again, you can save that using:

```
 #save the above using:
 df[df_dup].to_csv("duplicated_values.csv")
```

to see the duplicated values in the first column, use:

```
df[df_dup].iloc[:,0]
```

to get

```
Out[11]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

For unique calues, use `~` which is Python's not sign. So you're essentially subsetting `df` by values that are Not duplicates

```
df[~df_dup]

Out[29]:
      a     b
0   1.0  13.0
1   3.0   3.0
2   NaN   5.0
3  13.0   NaN
```

Comment: hi thanks for the speedy reply, I forgot to mention I am also brand new to python. I am getting a syntax error for your duplicate line:                            In [41]: df_dup = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())           Im reading through the docs now but I assume the 41 is referring to column 41?

Comment: Pandas internally uses the `xlrd` library to read files. While this is fast, the read-only mode in openpyxl can be even faster because it allows on-demand access, whereas xlrd must read all worksheets first before anything can be processed.

Comment: @lucyb, what's the error message you are getting? also, where do you see 41?

Comment: @CharlieClark, you're right in that `openpyxl` would be faster but I think there is a lot of overhead in getting it into Pandas, especially for someone who is new to Python. The `pd.read_excel` is a simple one line solution. No need to overkill it

Comment: @lucyb, i see what you're saying. The 41 is jus ta line marker, that's not actually python code. I removed the line numbers so that ou can just copy paste the code. NOTE that the data tables printed below lines such as `df[~df_dup]` are printed output, it's NOT code.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your responses @Gene , when executing it properly now I am not retrieving all the columns, only some. How would I modify this line: df_dup = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()) so that I am only looking for duplicates in the first column? After extracting it into a excel call I get the same spreadsheet except the cells is populated with a true and falses. Thanks EDIT: just saw your update, will test now and get back to you.

Comment: @lucyb, if you are only seeking duplicates in the first column then you can either subset the `df_dup` using `df_dup.iloc[:,0]` or you can search for duplicates only in the first column using `df.iloc[:,0].duplicated()`. To see only the duplicated values, use `df[df_dup]` (`df[df_dup].iloc[:,0]` for 1st column) and to save to to a .csv file, use `df[df_dup].to_csv("duplicated_values.csv")`. Also, if my answer suffices, please accept it.

Comment: thank you for your help, everything seems to working.

Comment: What overhead? Have you looked at the code in Pandas to do this? The sample I provided showed how elegant this can be.

Comment: @CharlieClark by overhead I meant that reading it in and converting it to python is about 12 lines (if I counted correctly) that include loops, generators, type conversion, indexing etc. The OP confused line markers for input code so why make it more difficult than it could be. Clearly, reading in speed isn't an inhibitor here, it's a 45k by 45 dataset, which isn't large. OP's task was to find duplicates, my code does that simply and quickly in less lines than it takes to read and convert from openpyxl to pandas. Also, if possible, could you remove the downvote?

Comment: I don't think that the proposed solution is the best way to identify duplicates in a single column which is what the question was. Pandas is a fantastic library but not the solution for everything.

Comment: You're right, it isn't THE best way to do it though one could argue that the best way to do it would be to write C/Java code specifically for this one task. From a practical standpoint, for someone new to Python (or programming in general), the higher the level, the better. Your solution is a more involved approach and doesn't explicitly address the duplication issue. Anyway, seems the issue is purely ideological and based on an insistence on using `openpyxl` so no point in discussing this any further.

Answer (score 0):

When working with read-only mode don't use the columns property to read a worksheet. This is because data is stored in rows so columns require the parser to continually re-read the file.

[This is an example](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe) of using openpyxl to convert worksheets into Pandas dataframes. It requires openpyxl 2.4 or higher, which at the time of writing can must be checked out.

Comment: I only want to look at cells from individual columns though not rows, starting with the first one.

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to create your own data structures for the columns yourself (a Pandas dataframe would be a good choice) and fill them as you work your way through the rows. There **is no other** way to do this because of the way the file format works.